# What's the most efficient way to identify unused columns?

Tags: spotfire

I have inherited a large Spotfire file with more than 100 columns. I want to reduce the file size by removing unused columns.

Aside from manually going through each visualization, is there a way to identify which columns are not being used?

Thanks!